# getHeight in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, measure

im trying to measure a ImageView, after my fragment is displayed, or if possible before.

I heared, that its not yet possible in the onActivityCreated. But somehow it works with the global Layout listener. -But how? -I have a method, wich measures and does some code, i just don't know when to call the method.

Can somebody gice an example?

the beginning of the measure method:

```js
 public void skalierung() {
  
  InputStream dots=getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.amountofdots);
  Bitmap dotsBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(dots);
  
  View mainframe=(View)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainframe);
  int breite=mainframe.getWidth();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set a `GlobalLayoutListener` you have to get `ViewTreeObserver`of your `View` using the `view.getViewTreeObserver()` method which :

> Returns the ViewTreeObserver for this view's hierarchy. The view tree observer can be used to get notifications when global events, like layout, happen.

After doing that well , you can `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` on your `ViewTreeObserever`

> `OnGlobalLayoutListener` : Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the global layout state or the visibility of views within the view tree changes.

and inside the `onGlobalLayout`method you can call the `getWidth` on the your desired view, here's an example :

```
    View mainframe=(View)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainframe);
ViewTreeObserver vto = mainframe.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        skalierung(); // here you can call the getWidth and getHeight methods
        ViewTreeObserver obs = mainframe.getViewTreeObserver();

        // you have to reset the ViewTreeObserver each time to ensure the reuse of the OnGlobalLayoutListener

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        } 
     }
    });
```

Hope it helps.